# How to load Facebook property file in java using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, facebook, spring, hibernate, properties

I am new to *spring* and *hibernate*.I was trying to connect my web application with Facebook.I have done this using the java script provided by Facebook but I want to connect Facebook using Spring Social. For this purpose I have to declare a properties file under `scr/main/resource` folder.I have done this but I am not using any xml file. I have a class which loads all the properties and Dao files.I don't know the method of loading the properties file of Facebook.

My `Applicationconfig` class is

```
    package net.codejava.spring.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAO;
import net.codejava.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import net.codejava.spring.model.User;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.codejava.spring")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }


    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("4261");

        return dataSource;
    }


    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        return properties;
    }
    /*private Properties getFacebookProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("spring.social.facebook.appId", "809280815833386");
        properties.put("spring.social.facebook.appSecret","24035c462c9d1fca367ff813436b15d8");

        return properties;
    }*/

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClasses(User.class);
        return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager(
                sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "userDao")
    public UserDAO getUserDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return new UserDAOImpl(sessionFactory);
    }
}
```

My `application.properties` file is

```
 spring.social.facebook.appId=appId
spring.social.facebook.appSecret=appSecret
```

Please provide the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("net.codejava.spring")
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
    public class ApplicationContextConfig {
    @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appId}")
        private String facebookAppID;
    }
```

Comment: @xrcwrn What about aapSecret

Comment: @Value("${spring.social.facebook.appSecret}")
        private String facebookAppSecret;